# Making HTML Widget resize Dynamically

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make my HTML widget be responsive and resize when the browser is resized. Here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu__item">
            <a href="" class="menu__link" target="_blank">
                <span class="menu__title">
                    <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="Executive">
                        Executive
                    </span>
                    <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Summary">
                        Summary
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="menu__item">
            <a " class="menu__link" target="_blank">
                <span class="menu__title">
                    <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="Display">
                        Display
                    </span>
                    <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Summary">
                        Summary
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="menu__item">
            <a href="" class="menu__link" target="_blank">
                <span class="menu__title">
                    <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="Facebook">
                        Facebook
                    </span>
                    <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Summary">
                        Summary
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="menu__item">
            <a href="" class="menu__link" target="_blank">
                <span class="menu__title">
                    <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="LinkedIn">
                        LinkedIn
                    </span>
                    <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Summary">
                        Summary
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="menu__item">
            <a href="" class="menu__link" target="_blank">
                <span class="menu__title">
                    <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="Search">
                        Search
                    </span>
                    <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Summary">
                        Summary
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
                <li class="menu__item">
            <a href="" class="menu__link" target="_blank">
                <span class="menu__title">
                    <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="Google">
                        Google
                    </span>
                    <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Analytics">
                        Analytics
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
 body {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: ;
      background: #FFF;
    }

    a {
      outline: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .navigation {
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
      font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
      font-size: 22px;
    }

    .menu {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      max-width: 1150px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-left: 0;
    }

    .menu__item {
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .menu__item:nth-child(n + 3) {
        display: none;
      }
      .menu__item:nth-child(2) .menu__link {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .menu__item:nth-child(n + 4) {
        display: none;
      }
      .menu__item:nth-child(3) .menu__link {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
      .menu__item:nth-child(n + 5) {
        display: none;
      }
      .menu__item:nth-child(4) .menu__link {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
    .menu__item:last-child .menu__link {
      border-right: 0;
    }

    .menu__link {
      display: block;
      padding: 6px 30px 3px;
      border-right: 2px dotted #ccd7d7;
    }
    .menu__link:hover .menu__first-word, .menu__link:focus .menu__first-word {
      transform: translate3d(0, -105%, 0);
    }
    .menu__link:hover .menu__second-word, .menu__link:focus .menu__second-word {
      transform: translate3d(0, 105%, 0);
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .menu__link {
        padding: 6px 40px 3px;
      }
    }

    .menu__title {
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .menu__first-word,
    .menu__second-word {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: transform .3s;
    }
    .menu__first-word::before,
    .menu__second-word::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: attr(data-hover);
    }

    .menu__first-word {
      color: #000000;
    }
    .menu__first-word::before {
      top: 105%;
      color: #000000;
    }

    .menu__second-word {
      color: #F37421;
    }
    .menu__second-word::before {
      bottom: 105%;
      color: #F37421;
    }
```

Please advice on the best method to adjust this to make it dynamic. I have removed the URL references through the HTML, as a side now.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,

Comment: You have to define media queries, to remove some padding and/or smaller font-size

Comment: _"Please let me know if you have any questions."_ - likewise. And if you can't come up with an _actual_ question yet, then please go read [ask].

Comment: @Cbroe that was a very helpful comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not made to be responsive, it is used to structure you page.
CSS is used to "design" it.
I would add a JavaScript script to dynamically resize the element !

If you're not used to JavaScript, don't worry, it is pretty simple to get started.

Here's some useful documentation :

- [JavaScript HTML DOM - Changing HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp)
- [JavaScript HTML DOM - Changing CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Hope that helped ;)

Comment: Thanks for this @ZyriabDsgn, i'll read through and make the adjustments!

Comment: @NakulB. You are welcome, I am not a web dev so there's probably other ways to perform that. If my post gave you the solution, please mark it as helping answer or something so, people passing by with the same question will find your post easily and marked as "solved". If you found another way, still it could be a good idea to mark your question as "solved" and share your solution ;)